# How to compress the swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, slider, vite

I only use one type of slider in the project But its total size is large (swiper-bundle.min.js:147kb and swiper-bundle.min.css:18k ).
How can I use only one part of it and compress it?
What do you suggestion?